# strcpy with 3 parameters, reference shows only 2

Tags: c++

Referencing http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy

`strcpy` has two parameters but the code I'm analyzing has three parameters. Is there another reference that could clarify what is happening with this code? I'm assuming it's setting the variable length. This is inside of a constructor.

```
HwCounterBase::HwCounterBase(const char* pName)
{
    _enabled = false;
    _value = 0;
    if (pName != NULL)
        STRCPY(_pName, COUNTER_NAME_LENGTH, pName);
    else
        _pName[0] = 0;
    _pLabel[0] = 0;
}
```

Comment: `STRCPY` is not `strcpy`. Looks like a macro. See if you can find the definition of it somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`STRCPY` is not `strcpy`, as C/C++ are case sensitive! Probably `STRCPY` is a preprocessor macro wrapping [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy).

```
#define STRCPY(dst, size, src)  strncpy(dst, src, size)
```

You should ask your IDE where `STRCPY` is defined.

Comment: hopefully it is not wrapping strncpy

Comment: C/C++ isn't a language. This question is tagged C++, not C.. If you feel it's relevant you could as well mention that C# is case sensitive.

Comment: @Default C++ incorporates nearly everything that C has and OP is attempting to use a C function so IMO saying C/C++ is relevant.

Comment: This was found in another source file associated with the project, thanks for helping me.

     `#define STRCPY(dst,size,src)        strcpy(dst,src)`

Comment: **Very bad practice!** Lets the user assume `size` is checked, though you may write into `dst` however much you wish - likely resulting in corrupting your memory. So do not  use `STRCPY()` at all!